# How to pass object name as parameter through variable defined as function onto another function?

Tags: javascript, object, scope, arguments

In my expanded code, I'm getting a TypeError and I think it's related to me not successfully passing an object as a parameter from one function, then through a variable defined as a function, and then on to the final function.

More specifically, I am calling the variable `executeOnce` (which is defined as a function) and passing the parameter `options` to it. This self-executing function then must pass along this `options` parameter to `funB()` (i.e., `funB(options)`) but I don't think the passed argument is making it to `funB()`. Hence the error.

What am I missing?

In the code below, it works if I change `funB(options);` to a string (i.e., `funB("options");`), but I can't do this because in my expanded code I am passing various arguments in.

```js
const obj = {
    options: {
        spam: 4
    },
};

function funB(options) {
    obj[options].spam = 6; // the console log below should print "6" but doesn't
}

var executeOnce = (function (options) {
    var executed = false;
    return function () {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            funB(options); // the function works if i change this to 'funB('options');'
        }
    };
})();

funA('options');
function funA(options) {
    executeOnce(options);
}

console.log('= ' + obj.options.spam)
```

Comment: Why do you call `funA('optionsA');`. I think its `funA('options');`

Comment: Thanks, @RyanNghiem, I updated my post to correct that mistake, but it doesn't solve my larger issue.

Comment: I’m not at a computer but I’m pretty sure since `executeOnce` returns a function, you actually need to call `executeOnce(options)()` in `funA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong at `executeOnce`, you use `immediate function` syntax to build a value for `executeOnce` variable (sound good), but `executeOnce` is a function without `any` parmas, you can see your return statement.

```
var executeOnce = (function (options) { // `options` - does not make sense
    var executed = false;
    return function () {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            funB(options);
        }
    };
})();
```

Try my way, return a function what has `options` is a parameter.

```
 var executeOnce = (function () {
    var executed = false;
    return function (options) {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            funB(options);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Brilliant! That works. It didn't occur to me to pass the `options` parameter in the return function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const obj = {
        options: {
            spam: 4
        },
    };

    function funB(options) {
        if(obj[options]==undefined)
          obj[options]={};
        obj[options].spam = 6;
    }

    var executeOnce = (function (options) {
        var executed = false;
        return function (options) {
            if (!executed) {
                executed = true;
                funB(options); // the function works if i change this to 'funB('options');'
            }
        };
    })();
    funA('optionsA');
    function funA(options) {
        executeOnce(options);
    }
    console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks, @MohammedMessaoudi but your solution doesn't solve the issue because using dot notation doesn't allow me to pass the object name in as an argument.

Comment: you now? if isn't okay! please lemme know!

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't work. It's just returning the object. But when I `console.log(obj.options.spam:);` it returns 4, not the updated 6 as it should.

Comment: you know that `var executeOnce = (function (` **options** `) {...` is undefined?
because you didn't pass any arg to executeOnce function in the first run!

Comment: Isn't' `executeOnce(options);` passing `options` to `var executeOnce`? I suspect the problem, as you suggest, is in this process of passing the argument from `function funA(options)` to `var executeOnce`, but I'm not sure how else to write it?

Comment: so why you set **"optionA"** ? why you didn't set funA('options'); ? so you can update spam property to 6

Comment: I should have set `options` not `optionsA`. That was a mistake that @Nate caught above. I corrected it in my post, but it wasn't the central problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be creating one more function than you need, but that doesn't break anything. The issue seems to be that the returned function (closure) doesn't know about `options`, which can be solved by passing `options` in as an argument when the returned function is called.

I gave the returned function a name, `newFunc`, and also added print statements throughout the script to clarify what's happening at each step (which made debugging way easier.)

```js
// Main
const obj = { options: { spam: 4 } };
funA(obj.options);
console.log("finally...");
console.log('obj.options.spam = ' + obj.options.spam);

// Functions
function funB(options){
  console.log("funB got..."); console.log(options);
  options.spam = 6;
  console.log("funB set options to..."); console.log(options);
}

function executeOnce(options){
  // context for closure (IIFE)
  console.log("executeOnce got..."); console.log(options);
  var executed = false;
  var newFunc = function(options){
    console.log("newFunc got..."); console.log(options);
    if(!executed){
      executed = true;
      funB(options);
    }
  };
  return newFunc(options);
};

function funA(options){ 
  console.log("funA got..."); console.log(options);
  executeOnce(options);
}
```

Comment: I see @hoangdv already pointed out the issue (and using only the debugger in their mind.) Good show.